# Beginner Java Program - All Numbers Entered Showing as Odd

Tags: java, debugging

I am taking a class on Java and the program I am working on is suppose to ask for a number and then show whether it is odd or even, all numbers show as odd. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
    int input, result;

    System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
    input = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());//Needed to make the scan of the
    //produce a integer rather than a string.

    result = input % NUM;//Orgininal coder forgot ";" ending. Syntax type. 

    if (result == 0) {
        System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is odd.");
    }
    else if (result != 0) {
        System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is even.");
    }
  }    
}
```

Any help is appreciated? I am just learning java.

Comment: This code does not compile as the result type of the assignation `result = 0` is `int` and not `boolean`. So this is not this program that shows always `odd`.

Comment: You need result == 0

Comment: In bluej it compiles, I add the == 0 and any number entered shows as odd, i just started this class

Comment: Alexis, as I mentioned I am just learning Java and your answer does not help at all for someone who is new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
int input, result;

System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
input = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());//Needed to make the scan of the
//produce a integer rather than a string.

result = input%2; 

if (result == 0) {
    System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is even.");
}
else if (result != 0) {
    System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is odd.");
}
}    
}
```

Remember:

> If result is an even number, the result will be 0.

Comment: And remember, you have to specify the class at the begining: class Test{

public static void main (String[] args){

Comment: in bluej using the code above, when compiling I get class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Add this AFTER the import java.util.Scanner; : class YOURCLASSNAME{ and then, after that line, add this one: public static void main (String[] args){

Comment: Marked your answer as the answer that got my code working, this is the second java program I have ever worked on

Answer (score 0):

It should read `input % 2`

You will then have to swap odd and even since a number is even if there is 0 remainder when you divide by 2.

And it should be `if (result == 0)`

This code works for me:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddEven
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
    int input, result;

    System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
    input = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());//Needed to make the scan of the
    //produce a integer rather than a string.

    result = input % 2;//Orgininal coder forgot ";" ending. Syntax type. 

   if (result == 0) {
        System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is even.");
    }
    else if (result != 0) {
        System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is odd.");
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Does the code compile or not?

Comment: It compiles, but when asking for a number, and entering a number such as 4 it outputs the number as odd no matter what number you enter, when adding input % 2 it still shows any number entered as odd

Comment: I presume you have put import java.util.Scanner; outside the class

Comment: Note that instead of public class OddEven you will have to insert your own class name which you can see at the top of the code editing box.

Comment: @user160246 Glad you got it working. Good luck with your future programs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class OddEven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
        int input, result;
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        result = input%2;        
        if (result == 0)
            System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is even.");
        else
            System.out.println("\n\n Number " + input + " is odd.");
        scan.close();
    }    
}
```